# creating your own dataset similar to cityscapes format

Tags: training, datasets, image-segmentation

I'm trying to train a neural network with my own dataset. The neural network can accept the [cityscape format](https://www.cityscapes-dataset.com).

Is there any application that can give mask/segmented image, instance image, label IDs images and JSON file, similar to cityscape dataset format?

Basically, I want to create my own dataset similar to the cityscape dataset format.

Comment: This part "Is there any application that can give mask/segmented image, instance image, label IDs images and JSON file" is still not clear. Which application are you talking about? Where do these "mask/segmented image, instance image, label IDs images and JSON file" come from? In "Is there any application that can give", can give to what? To the neural network? As far as I understand, you want to create a dataset similar to cityscape, but from raw data. Is this what you want? If yes, explain more about your raw data and where it comes from.